# Clip Raster with Polygon by GDAL in C++

Tags: c++, gdal

I am trying to clip a raster using a polygon an GDAL. At the moment i get an error that there is a read access violation when initializing the WarpOperation. I can access my Shapefile and check the num of features so the access is fine i think. Also i can access my Raster Data (GetProjectionRef).. All files are in the same CRS. Is there a way to use GdalWarp with Cutline?
I enter the following command in the terminal, the operation is done correctly:

```
gdalwarp -of GTiff -cutline polygon.shp -crop_to_cutline input.tif output.tif
```

But when I try to do this with this C++ code, the processing ends, but all the output files are 0 (zero). I checked similar posts and even tried other sample codes but the result was the same.

```
int main()
{
    GDALAllRegister();
    const char* rasterPath = "input.tif";
    const char* vectorPath = "polygon.shp";
    const char* outputRasterPath = "output.tif";

    GDALDataset* rasterDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset*>(GDALOpen(rasterPath, GA_ReadOnly));
    GDALDataset* vectorDataset = static_cast<GDALDataset*>(GDALOpenEx(vectorPath, GDAL_OF_UPDATE, nullptr, nullptr, nullptr));

    OGRLayer* vectorLayer = vectorDataset->GetLayer(0);

    OGRSpatialReference* rasterSRS = new OGRSpatialReference(rasterDataset->GetProjectionRef());

    OGRSpatialReference* vectorSRS = vectorLayer->GetSpatialRef();
    OGRCoordinateTransformation* transform = OGRCreateCoordinateTransformation(vectorSRS, rasterSRS);

    OGRGeometry* clipGeometry = vectorLayer->GetNextFeature()->GetGeometryRef();

    GDALDriver* driver = GetGDALDriverManager()->GetDriverByName("GTiff");
    GDALDataset* outputDataset = driver->Create(outputRasterPath, rasterDataset->GetRasterXSize(), rasterDataset->GetRasterYSize(), 1, GDT_Float32, nullptr);
    outputDataset->SetProjection(rasterDataset->GetProjectionRef());
    double adGeoTransform[6];
    rasterDataset->GetGeoTransform(adGeoTransform);
    outputDataset->SetGeoTransform(adGeoTransform);

    OGRGeometry* cutlineGeometry = clipGeometry->clone();

    GDALWarpOptions* warpOptions = GDALCreateWarpOptions();
    warpOptions->hSrcDS = rasterDataset;
    warpOptions->hDstDS = outputDataset;
    warpOptions->nBandCount = 1;
    warpOptions->panSrcBands = (int*)CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * warpOptions->nBandCount);
    warpOptions->panSrcBands[0] = 1;
    warpOptions->panDstBands = (int*)CPLMalloc(sizeof(int) * warpOptions->nBandCount);
    warpOptions->panDstBands[0] = 1;
    warpOptions->papszWarpOptions = CSLDuplicate(nullptr);
    warpOptions->eWorkingDataType = GDT_Float32;
    warpOptions->pTransformerArg = GDALCreateGenImgProjTransformer( rasterDataset, 
                                                                    rasterDataset->GetProjectionRef(), 
                                                                    outputDataset, 
                                                                    outputDataset->GetProjectionRef(), 
                                                                    TRUE, 1000, 1);
    warpOptions->pfnTransformer = GDALGenImgProjTransform;
    warpOptions->pfnProgress = GDALTermProgress;
    warpOptions->hCutline = cutlineGeometry;

    GDALWarpOperation warpOperation;
    warpOperation.Initialize(warpOptions);

    warpOperation.ChunkAndWarpImage(0, 0, outputDataset->GetRasterXSize(), outputDataset->GetRasterYSize());

    TransformCutlineToSource(outputDataset, reinterpret_cast<OGRGeometryH>(cutlineGeometry), &(warpOptions->papszWarpOptions), NULL);

    GDALDestroyGenImgProjTransformer(warpOptions->pTransformerArg);
    GDALDestroyWarpOptions(warpOptions);
    delete cutlineGeometry;
    delete clipGeometry;
    delete transform;
    GDALClose(outputDataset);
    GDALClose(vectorDataset);
    GDALClose(rasterDataset);
    return 0;
}
```

Is there a way to make the result correct after transformation?

Comment: Where do you have the read access violation? Here: `warpOperation.Initialize(warpOptions);` ? Can you show the stacktrace from gdb and possibly from valgrind?

Comment: term process is done. but my outImage tif contains only 0.